# 32 bit works fine but 64 bit gives error: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location

Tags: c++, exception, com, crash, 32bit-64bit

My Visual Studio C++ 2008 project builds the executable in 32 bit platform, in both debug and release modes, without any issue and executable runs and generates expected results.

I have some matrices with the size of more than 26000 rows by 26000 columns (double type) and in 32 bit platform I can not allocate memory to this matrices. Therefore I have to switch to 64 bit platform.

On 64 bit platform I can build my executable without any error (both debug and release modes) but when trying to run the executable I receive the following message in debug mode:

[image]

And the following message in release mode:

[image]

I stepped through the code in debugging mode and the first message I receive is this (which occurs at Microsoft COM):

[image]

Every time I click on continue on the previous message, I get a different error message occurring at different locations of a file named  `STAADLibBentley.tli` like the two ones shown below as a sample:

[image]
[image]

At the top of the `STAADLibBentley.tli` the following comments are written, which shows the TLB file is for Win32 and the compiler is implementing a wrapper for TLB file to use it in 64 bit platform.

[image]

Looks like this `STAADLibBentley.tli` file is a wrapper implemented automatically by the compiler, related to `STAADLibBentley.tlb` file which I'm using in my C++ code like below and is related to STAAD APIs, STAAD is a software with which I'm communicating by TLB libraries. I'm using the TLB file like this:

[image]

Now the question is, if the compiler is taking care of writing a wrapper for the Win32 TLB file to use it in 64 platform, why I'm receiving those error messages mentioned above inside `STAADLibBentley.tli` file. Does anybody know what is the possible reason?

Comment: `(26000 * 26000 * sizeof(double)) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) = 5GB`. You cannot allocate that much. I very much doubt you can. I run a 64-bit system with 32GB ram and I can still only allocate 4GB at any given instance. I don't think the computer can find more than 4GB contiguously.. OR there is a limit.

Comment: @Brandon I'm wondering how one can handle large matrices. Any option?

Comment: Well.. I used the no-throw version of new just now and was able to allocate 21GB contiguously but lagged like hell! I was following this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952731/allocating-more-than-4gb-memory-in-a-64-bit-system Without the no-throw, it threw `std::bad_alloc` at 4GB.. I guess you can either use no-throw OR just allocate in REASONABLE chunks rather than trying to allocate all 5GBs at once.. Maybe allocate 100mb - 500mb at a time and keep track of it. Not every computer has huge amounts ram. Not sure that this solution will be good for matrices though..

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be `bad_alloc` - are we sure that the code is actually operating correctly in general? Do you get the same problem if you use a much smaller size?

Comment: Also, is it possible that the code contains "hard-coded sizes", such as using `4` instead of `sizeof(*int)`?

Comment: @Brandon In the 32 bit version of my C++ code, when I want to allocate the 26000x26000 matrix, I get the same `std::bad_alloc` error as you get without the no-throw. For small matrices, the 32 bit version of C++ code works good.

Comment: @MatsPetersson In the 32 bit version of my C++ code, when I want to allocate the 26000x26000 matrix, I get the `std::bad_alloc` error. But or small matrices, the 32 bit version of C++ code works good.

Comment: Right, your current error is not bad_alloc, but appears to be a memory corruption type error, which made me think that something might be writing out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to people familiar with API of STAAD software, I was told that the API is a component of 32 bit Microsoft COM not 64 bit. Fortunately, there are some tricks to use 32 bit COM in 64 bit platform like the following links, I may give it a try:

http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

[Getting the GUID of an installed COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112880/getting-the-guid-of-an-installed-com-object)